# Check based on value of previously captured group value

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regular expression. I want the .com to match only if it is not www.somesite.com but match if it is www.somesite.info.

Is there a way to achieve that? Essentially within the com|info section, can I somehow check the value of the previously captured group value

```
((?!www).*)\.someveryspecificsite\.(com|info)

www.someveryspecificsite.info - should match
anystring.someveryspecificsite.info - should match
anystring.someveryspecificsite.com - should match
www.someveryspecificsite.com - should not match
anything else - should not match
```

Comment: @0m3r why not provide your answer as an answer instead of a comment? 

....also it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
((?:.*?someveryspecificsite\.info$)|(?:^(?!w{3}).*?someveryspecificsite\.?com$))
```

[Solution on Regexpal](http://www.regexpal.com/?fam=97303).

Comment: I am trying to understand, how does this incorporate the somesite part?

Comment: Did you mean to literally match "somesite" instead of any site? Just replace the `.+?` with `somesite\.` Though now I don't think you should be using a regular expression at all since you can do literal matches instead.

Comment: Thank you. One more question - so right now the regex matches somesite.info. The match should only be if there is a string and a dot, so like, somestring.somesite.info. If you have any hints on that, I will appreciate

Comment: I've updated the solution for you which should be what you're after :)